# Test directory if it contains a set of files based on their extensions

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls

How can I test a directory to see if it contains files typically used for a website? I've searched and found how to test for one extension at a time, which led me to do this:

```
c1=`ls -1 /var/www/*.htm 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
c2=`ls -1 /var/www/*.html 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
c3=`ls -1 /var/www/*.php 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $c1 != 0 ] || [ $c2 != 0 ] || [ $c3 != 0 ]; then    
    echo true
fi
```

However, this does not strike me as being particularly efficient, as obviously there are a great many different file types that could be used for a website. Is there a `case` statement I could utilize instead?

Comment: any file *could* be on a website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working entirely from your example, you could simplify the code a little

```
found=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.htm -o -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' \) | wc -l)
if [[ $found -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo Possibly a website
fi
```

Or

```
found=$(ls -d *.htm *.html *.php 2>/dev/null)
if [[ -n "$found" ]]
then
    echo Possibly a website
fi
```

Or even

```
echo Possibly a website
```

Comment: There we go.  Exactly what I am looking for.  I did not know that `ls` by itself was capable of that.

Thank you

Comment: @Kevin `ls` isn't doing anything special. The shell expands the wildcards where possible and passes the resulting list to `ls`.